# How to pass more than one argument to SLOT function in qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, arguments, qt5, signals-slots

As a sample, i have a function

```
void MyClass::foo( int i, int j ){ cout << i+j; }
```

and i wish that one signal execute a slot on some function of the class

```
connect( Object, SIGNAL( mysignal() ), SLOT( this->foo(1,2) ) );
```

With one argument its work, but show errors with 2 or more arguments on slot.

Answer (score 4):

QT has excellent documentation on signals and slots http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html, make sure you understand the syntax. In your case it will be something like

```
connect( pointerToObjectEmittingTheSignal, SIGNAL(my_signal(int, int) ), 
         this, SLOT(my_slot(int, int));
```

In addition, your signal declaration should take two arguments of type `int` and `int`

```
signals:
     void my_signal(int, int);
```

Comment: I try this method before, and dont work. Always i put a var in slot funcion its generate the error 

QObject::connect: No such slot MyClass::foo(i,j)

Comment: it should be `SLOT(foo(int, int)` not `SLOT(foo(1,2))`

Comment: But where i set 'i' and 'j' ?

Comment: You set `i` and `j` when you emit the signal, for example `emit my_signal(i,j)`. Every time the signal is emitted the corresponding slot will be called with those arguments, namely `i` and `j`. Read Qt documentation on signals and slots, this is basic knowledge. The tutorial will explain the concept in greater detail and depth that I can give you here.

Comment: happy to help. Also, check out this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtyCM4BTbYo

Answer (score 3):

Note that in Qt5 you can use the [new signal/slot syntax](https://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html) and write this:

```
connect( pointerToObjectEmittingTheSignal, &MyClass::my_signal, 
         this, &MyOtherClass::my_slot);
```

the advantage being that if you make a mistake you'll get a compile-time error instead of a runtime error.